TSAN: Reporting intermittent data race
I have been using TSAN build for detecting thread data races in my project and it works pretty well in most of the cases. At times, I understand TSAN could potentially report false positives, harmless races, or in-fact also miss reporting some genuine issues due to un instrumented shared libs etc, but under what situation does TSAN generates report intermittently?
Simply running a test 5-6 times, i see TSAN generating data race report for 2-3 times and missing other times (No thread race reported). I thought the behavior should be consistent always irrespective of thread(s) being scheduled by OS scheduler in any order.
Thanks,
I tried reading many articles on the internet and stack-overflow but none seems to describe why could there be an intermittent ness in this reporting.
